# CollapsibleBanners - Save screen space when viewing questions

Tags: script

### Preview

[image: CollapsibleBanners-Preview]

### What is CollapsibleBanners?

CollapsibleBanners is a userscript that allows you to collapse the 'Closed' banner on questions. This helps save screen space.

#### Download

Auto-update version (recommended): [minified](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CollapsibleBanners/collapsiblebanners.latest.min.user.js) | [unminified](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CollapsibleBanners/collapsiblebanners.latest.user.js)

| Version | Minified | Unminified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Version 1.0](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/CollapsibleBanners/v1.0) | [install](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CollapsibleBanners/v1.0/script.min.user.js) | [install](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CollapsibleBanners/v1.0/script.user.js) |

#### Browser Support

| IE | Chrome | Firefox | Safari | Edge | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔️ 6+ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ 5.1+ | ✔️ 12.1+ | ✔️ 11.5+ |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)